# Gutenberg templates disappear with child-theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a site running with Gutenberg.
There are templates.
I need now to install a child theme (to customize Woocommerce emails templates).
When I install my child-theme, all the templates and templates parts disappear and reappear when I reactivate native theme.
I there a way to make the old templates running with the child-theme?

Comment: Do you confirm that you defined `Template: your-main-theme-folder-name` in your child theme `style.css` correctly?

Comment: yes, this line is in my style.css of child-theme

Comment: I talk about the page templates not the site template, so I don't think that the soluton is in the style.css file.

Answer (score 1):

You can [export a copy of your themes templates and styles](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/site-editor/#how-to-export-templates-and-styles) via
`Site Editor > Appearance > Editor > [...] Options > Tools > Export`

The exported zip will contain your template files which you can import as a complete theme or re-use the template/template parts with your child theme.